# how can i display the single quote inside awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have this awk statemnt and its working fine

```
awk '{a= a","$1}END{print a}' file.txt
```

I want that in my output my $1 field shoube surrounded with single quotes

how can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
awk -v q="'" '{a= a","q$1q}END{print a}' file.txt
```

Another way:

```
awk '{a= a",\x27"$1"\x27"}END{print a}' file.txt
```

Another way:

```
awk '{a= a",'"'"'"$1"'"'"'"}END{print a}' file.txt
```

Another:

```
awk '{a= a",'\''"$1"'\''"}END{print a}' file.txt
```

Comment: updated the answer, there might be other ways to do this though

Comment: here is a reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html